# Why is the random number I'm generating not changing within a loop? C

Tags: c, random, numbers

Here is my current code. I am trying to create a game whereby the computer generates a random number and the user has to guess if it's higher or lower than the shown number. However I cannot get the random number to change it always stays the same.

So how can I get the random number to change so that the user can keep guessing rather than getting stuck in a loop of:
Higher or lower than 6?
0
Higher or lower than 6?
0

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()

{
  int rdmnum;
  int rdm2;
  int guess;
  int x = 1;

  srand (time(NULL));
  rdmnum = rand () % 9;


  printf("To guess higher enter 1, to guess lower enter 0.\n");


printf("Higher or lower than %d?\n", rdmnum);
scanf("%d", &guess);
do {
  if (guess == 1 && guess >= rdmnum){
    printf("Higher or lower than %d?\n", rdmnum);        
    scanf("%d", &guess);
    x = 1;
  }
  else {
     x = 0;
  }

  if (guess == 0 && guess <= rdmnum){
    printf("Higher or lower than %d?\n", rdmnum);
    scanf("%d", &guess);
    x = 1;
  }
  else {
    x = 0;
  }
  } while (x ==1);

  if (x ==0) {
    printf("Incorrect the number was %d, game over!\n", rdmnum);
  return 0;
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you expect `rdmnum` to get random numbers magically in the loop? You called `rand`just once before the loop.

Comment: do i understand correctly that 0 always mean guessing "lower" ? Cause you appear to compare guess (1 or 0) with this random number

Comment: Yes that is correct. 1 is a guess for higher, 0 is a guess for lower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer to why `rdmnum` isn't changing:**

Try this:

```
//code
do {
  rdmnum = rand () % 9;               //Take note of this line!
  if (guess == 1 && guess >= rdmnum){
    printf("Higher or lower than %d?\n", rdmnum);  
//rest of code
```

You were only running the `rand()` function once, outside of the loop.  Therefore, you were only calculating a random number once, and using it each time.

By moving it into the loop, each time the loop iterates, you generate a new random number.

**Edit:**

Following your comment, you have bigger problems with the algorithm.

From the your declaration of two random numbers and some extra points in the question I'd glossed over, your problem is more than just `rdmnum` not changing.

Your `if`s need work too; your second `if` overwrites the results of the first.

You can try:

```
if (guess == 1 && guess >= rdmnum)
{
    printf("Higher or lower than %d?\n", rdmnum);        
    scanf("%d", &guess);
    x = 1;
}
else if (guess == 0 && guess <= rdmnum)
{
    printf("Higher or lower than %d?\n", rdmnum);
    scanf("%d", &guess);
    x = 1;
}
else 
{
    x = 0;
}
```

This way, if the player guesses 1 (and gets it right) then the second `if` won't set `x` to 0 every time.
Additionally, you are testing a number in the range 0-9 against a number in the range 0-1.  This will *very* often result in the input `0` being correct but `1` will very rarely be correct - only when your question is output as:

```
Higher or lower than 0?
```

I've taken the liberty to re-write your program with simpler logic.  I've also added in the use of the second random number so that you are guessing whether `random number #1` is bigger or smaller than `random number #2`

```
int main ()
{
    int target;
    int displayed;
    int guess;
    int difference;

    srand (time(NULL));
    printf("To guess higher enter 1, to guess lower enter 0.\n");

    while(true)
    {
        //we randomise both the displayed number and the hidden number to compare it to
        //and ensure that they are not equal
        do
        {
            target = rand () % 9;
            displayed = rand () % 9;
        } while (displayed == target)

        //ask the question:
        printf("Higher or lower than %d?\n", displayed);
        scanf("%d", &guess);
        if (guess == 0 || guess == 1)
        {

            //now see if they were correct
            difference = (target - displayed) > 0;
            if (guess == difference)
            {
                //they were right
                printf("Correct the number was %d!\n", target);
            }
            else
            {   //they were wrong - exit the loop
                printf("Incorrect the number was %d, game over!\n", target);
                break;
            }
        }
        //bad input - just loop
        printf("Incorrect input!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*also, fyi, random is usually abbreviated to:* `rnd` *not* `rdm`. *Not a major thing but helps others when they read your code*

Comment: I implemented this into the code. It works successfully if you guess 0, however if you guess higher it immediately returns as an Incorrect number. Any idea why?

Comment: I can see the error in it now. I didn't think about the < or > condition in relation to the fact that the answers are always 1/0. I altered your code slightly as it was showing compiling errors. '    {
                target = rand () % 9;
                displayed = rand () % 9;
            } while (displayed == target);' So now its will recreate a new random number if displayed and target are the same.

Comment: Ah yes, a typo, sorry. Fixed.  If I've helped, feel free to upvote / accept.

Comment: One more question though, I don't understand how this bit works. difference = (target - displayed) > 0;
            if (guess == difference) , if the target is 4 but the displayed is 8 then (4 - 8) > 0; doesn't make sense. If the target is 8 but displayed is 4 then (8 - 4) > 0; means difference is 4 but the only inputs are 1 or 0 so how could it be correct?

Comment: `difference = (target - displayed) > 0` finds the difference between the two random values (`target - displayed`) and then compares that to `0`.  The result of this is `1` if `target` is bigger than `displayed`, and `0` otherwise (`>` returns a boolean - `1`(true) or `0`(false)).  This can then be directly compared to the input by the player. `if (guess == difference)` is true if they are correct.

Comment: This could be reduced to one line (allowing the difference variable to be removed - I put it in there as it is easier to see how it works): `if(guess == ((target - displayed) > 0)){}`

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive and detailed assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to have random numbers instead of just one random number. So add

```
rdmnum = rand () % 9;
```

Just after the `do{` in order to generate a random number in every iteration. Also note that you need to include `stdlib.h` in your program.

P.S: The logic used in your code does not make any sense to me for a guessing game...

Comment: Could you expand on the logic issue for me at all?

Comment: @hysteriaistic , Please edit your question with the expected output. It would be better if you ask a new question as the current question is answered.

Comment: @hysteriaistic I've touched on the logic in my updated answer

Comment: @hysteriaistic, you'll also need `#include <time.h>`. Did you really compile and run the program you posted?

Comment: @WeatherVane , Just `stdlib.h` and `stdio.h` are required. Why include `time.h`?

Comment: Because of `srand (time(NULL));`

Comment: My compiler gives "warning C4013: 'time' undefined; assuming extern returning int" and although it linked and ran, it's unsatisfactory. It's best to have no warnings at all, so in addition the randomization should have been `srand ((unsigned int)time(NULL));`

Comment: @WeatherVane , You are right! I thought that it works properly as it generates random numbers as expected! Thanks .